# Getting database ID from combobox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox

I have got a problem.

[image: Pressing button "Guardar"]

I need to get id_subcategoria in 2 combobox "1". I have this code:

```
void fill_cbsubcategoria(int masterId)
{
    cbsubcategoria.Items.Clear();
    cbproduto.Items.Clear();
    cbproduto.Text = "Escolha o produto";
    txtquantidade.Text = null;
    txtpreco.Text = null;
    txtiva.Text = null;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string Query = "select * from Subcategoria where id_categoria = @mid";
        SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
        createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mid", masterId);
        SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int id_subcategoria = (int)dr.GetInt32(0);
            string subcategoria = (string)dr.GetString(1);
            cbsubcategoria.Items.Add(id_subcategoria.ToString() + " - " + new SubCategoriaHolder(id_subcategoria, subcategoria));
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

And I need to have id_subcategoria, when clicking at "Guardar".

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string Query = "insert into dbPAP.Produtos (id_subcategoria, nome_produto, quantidade, preco_unitario, iva, imagem)" + "values('" + "I NEED THAT ID FROM COMBOBOX" + this.txt_nproduto.Text + this.txtquantidade.Text + this.txtpreco.Text + this.txtiva.Text + "') ;";
        SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Adicionado com sucesso!");
        while (dr.Read())
        {

        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here's my button guardar code.

Note: I don't want SelectedValue from combobox, I want to get id_subcategoria from DataBase.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ID's to a array List, while loading the elements to the combo Box, the Selected index from the combo box should reference to the according id in the List

Comment: why? what does this array list contain? try to set a breakpoint an look, what it contains